while he is away for a while
a. I am staying in his flat while he is away for a while.
Does 'for a while' modify 'I am staying in his flat' or 'he is away'?
Is it possible that the intended meaning is I am staying in his flat during part of the duration of his absence?
Many thanks

It modifies "he is away", but there's no implication about whether or not your stay lasts for the entire time.



I am staying in his flat [while he is away for a while].




I am staying in his flat [while he is away] for a while.


(1) is more likely, that is,
I am staying in his flat, while he is away for a while.
As commented, there's no implication about whether the stay is throughout the period or just a part of it.
To mean (2), it would likely be
I am staying in his flat, while he is away, for a while.
or better
I am staying in his flat for a while, while he is away.


I am staying in his flat while he is away for a while.

There is no way to know, without context, whether this is a "house-sitting" scenario or someone letting a friend stay in their flat for a bit while they're away.  "while" is variable and imprecise in its meaning. It could mean "for the entire duration" or "for some chunk of time".
